# Transformation of nested object

Tags: javascript

I am new to **JavaScript** and **Node JS**

want to transform the following nested object with `student`

**Data:**

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "B",
        "children": [{

                "id": 3,
                "name": "C"
            },
            {

                "id": 4,
                "name": "D"

            }
        ]
    }]
}]
```

to

**Expected:**

```
[{
    "student": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "A"
    },
    "children": [{
        "student": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "B"
        },
        "children": [{
                "student": {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "C"
                }
            },
            {
                "student": {
                    "id": 4,
                    "name": "D"
                }
            }
        ]
    }]
}]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are seeking a solution for an array with multiple student objects. So you can use the `map` method to modify them.

```
const original = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "A",
    "children": [{
        "id": 2,
        "name": "B",
        "children": [{

                "id": 3,
                "name": "C"
            },
            {

                "id": 4,
                "name": "D"

            }
        ]
    }]
}]

const modified = original.map(stu => {
  return {
    student: {
      id: stu.id,
      name: stu.name,
    },
    children: stu.children
  }
})
```